# How to properly add a profile and extensions to ChromeDriver in arquillian.xml

Tags: xml, testing, browser, selenium-chromedriver, jboss-arquillian

I am trying to run drone (chromedriver) with custom arguments and extensions. However I haven' t been able to properly configure arquillian.xml in order for the browser to run with them installed/configured.

arquillian.xml:

```
   ...
  <extension qualifier="webdriver">
    <property name="browser">chrome</property>
    <property name="chromeDriverBinary">C:\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe</property>
    <property name="chromeArguments">user-data-dir=>C:\\path\\to\\BrowserProfile</property>
    <property name="chromeExtensions">>C:\\path\\to\\\ModHeader_v2.1.1.crx</property>
    <property name="chromePrintOptions">true</property>
  </extension>
</arquillian>
```

Am I missing something? How do I get drone to load the profile and extension?

I have been able to run an instance with my settings when I use this:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addExtensions(new File("/path/to/extension.crx"));
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options); 
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

and

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("user-data-dir=/path/to/your/custom/profile");
```

However this instantiated a different browser along with drone. Is there a way to add these settings to drone (before it instantiates)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to set these ChromeOptions properties use specific parameters that correspond to the names of set/add methods defined in the ChromeOptions class (with a prefix "chrome").
Concretely in your case, you need to use the parameter `chromeArguments`
For more information see:
http://arquillian.org/blog/2016/09/14/arquillian-extension-drone-2-0-1-Final/

I've also noticed that you are using `chromeDriverBinary` property to set the path to the webdriver. If you used the latest version of Drone you wouldn't need to do it because of the automatic download feature. It basically downloads the latest version of chrome webdriver and caches it in your home directory. For more information about this feature see: https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-extension-drone/#automatic-download